# Change XML Schema from Attributes to Elements

Tags: xml, schema

I've tried setting this up lots of ways but I can't get it to work.  I need to have an element called "ShipmentUpdates" that is a type of "ShipmentUpdate" where "ShipmentUpdate" is set to unbounded.  When I first created this schema, I used attributes for the "ShipmentUpdate" piece, but I have recently found out these need to be elements instead.  When I tried to just change the attibutes to elements, I get the message: "Element is not permitted."

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="ShipmentUpdates">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" ref="ShipmentUpdate"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="ShipmentUpdate">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="stockNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="qtyRequest" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="qtyShip" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="primeLine" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="trackingNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="found" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I think all I had to do was add a "sequence" tag around the attributes then change them to elements.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <xsd:element name="ShipmentUpdates">
<xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="ShipmentUpdate" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="stockNumber"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="qtyRequest"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="qtyShip"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="trackingNumber"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:boolean" name="found"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="primeLine"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```